# Remove Image preview when Clear button selected

Tags: jquery

I was able to find a solution to upload an image and preview the image to the form.

However, I am having a hard time to remove the preview of the image once I select the clear button.

Here is the script that uploads and previews the image to the form:

```
/*Upload email to form*/
        $(document).ready(function() {
            if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
                $("#files").on("change", function(e) {
                    var files = e.target.files,
                    filesLength = files.length;
                    for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
                        var f = files[i]
                        var fileReader = new FileReader();
                        fileReader.onload = (function(e) {
                            var file = e.target;
                            $("<span class=\"pip\">" +
                            "<img class=\"imageThumb\" src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" title=\"" + file.name + "\"/>" +
                            "<br/><span class=\"remove\">x</span>" +
                            "</span>").insertAfter("#files");
                            $(".remove").click(function(){
                                $(this).parent(".pip").remove();
                                $('#files').val("");
                            });
                        });
                        fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
                    }
                });
            } 
            else {
                alert("Your browser doesn't support to File API")
            }
        });
/***********************/
```

The following below is my function that resets the form. I am able to clear the name of the file but not the image that is previewing in the form. I thought by adding `.find('#files').removeAtr('src');` would remove the preview but it did not:

```
/*Clears the Form*/
        function resetForm() {
            $('form[name="email"] input:reset').click(function () {
                $('form[name="myform"]')
                    .find(':radio, :checkbox').removeAttr('checked').end()
                    .find('textarea, :text, select, file').val('')
                    .find('#files').removeAtr('src');

                return false;
            });
        }
/**********************/
```

Here is part of the form where I upload and preview the users image. Any suggestions on how to remove the preview would be greatly appreciated.:

```
<form class="form-style-5" id="myform" name="email">
<fieldset>
    <legend><span class="number">3</span> Image Attachment</legend>
    <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
</fieldset>

    <input onclick="return checkForm(this.form)" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <input type="reset" value="Clear" onclick="return resetForm(this.form);" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `input` already has the feature to reset the form, so there is no need to call `resetForm()` on clicking the `input`:

```
<input type="reset" value="Clear" onclick="return resetForm(this.form);" />
```

So replace that with this:

```
<input type="reset" value="Clear" />
```

And add this to the script:

```
// Clears the image previews on resetting the form.
$( 'form[name="email"]' ).on( 'reset', function() {
    $( this ).find( '.pip' ).remove();
} );
```

You can remove `resetForm()` from the page, or if you want to keep it, then use this instead of what you have now:

```
/*Clears the Form and the image previews.*/
        function resetForm(form) {
            $(form || 'form[name="email"]')
                .find(':radio, :checkbox').removeAttr('checked').end()
                .find('textarea, :text, select, :file').val('').end()
                .find('.pip').remove();

            return false;
        }
/**********************/
```

And here's an example of using the `resetForm()` with a standard `button` (i.e. `button` with a `type` of `button`):

```
<button onclick="return resetForm();">Reset</button>
```

Comment: @ Sally: Thank you for your help. I have tried it and it is working to remove the preview of the image. However, I am not seeing why, it is not reset the input field for the email. Can you explain why?

Comment: @ sally: Nevermind, I figured it out. Thank you again for your assistance

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out! All the best. =)